# Error running Spark on Databricks: constructor public XXX is not whitelisted

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, whitelist

I was using Azure Databricks and trying to run some example python code from [this page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html).

But I get this exception:

> py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Constructor public org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression(java.lang.String) is not whitelisted.

Answer (score 16):

This error shows up with some library methods when using High Concurrency cluster with credential pass through enabled.  If that is your scenario a work around that may be an option is to use a different cluster mode.

> py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: ... is not whitelisted
> This exception is thrown when you have accessed a method that Azure Databricks has not explicitly marked as safe for Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough clusters. In most cases, this means that the method could allow a user on a Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough cluster to access another user’s credentials.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough

Comment: Thank you so much for this. If you don't know that, how are you supposed to solve this issue ? ...

Comment: I can confirm that it works on a normal cluster without credential passthrough. I'm currently using databricks runtime 6.1 on a standard mode cluster, data lake access is done via service principal.

Comment: What if I cannot use different cluster?

Comment: Correct URL since I cannot Edit the answer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough