# DatabricksError py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.rdd() is not whitelisted

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Whenever I use the Spark collect() action operation to retrieve all the elements of the RDD/DataFrame/Dataset I get the error:

```
py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.rdd() is not whitelisted on class class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD
```

The collect I use is as follows:

```
MyPath.limit(1).rdd.collect()
```

Can someone let me know what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Any thoughts on what might be causing this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error running Spark on Databricks: constructor public XXX is not whitelisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55427770/error-running-spark-on-databricks-constructor-public-xxx-is-not-whitelisted)

Comment: Hi @Koedlt, unfortunately, I'm faced with same problem the person faced that submitted that question - I don't have the permission to change the Cluster mode. Do you have any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.rdd() is not whitelisted on class class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD
```

**The above error occurs if the Cluster is in “Shared access mode.”**

**In Unity Catalog Shared Cluster mode, RDD functionality has been turned off due to security concerns.** This is because the cluster, in its shared mode, also supports the older Hive Metastore Table ACL, which cannot safely whitelist all classes for security purposes.

**The only possible resolution is as below:**

- Kindly use a different cluster mode, **Single user** (Recommended), or **No isolation Shared Mode**. (No UC)